What is this pattern called and is it a good practice? Strategy pattern?
I refactoring some Python code and one time I came up with a kind of pattern that I can not really assign a name (I'm not really familiar with patterns though).
Here is an attempt on an abstract version of what I have done:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from enum import Enum


class AbstractThing(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        pass


class ConcreteThingOne(AbstractThing):
    def do_something(self):
        print("CONCRETETHINGONE DID SOMETHING IN A WAY CONCRETETHINGONE WOULD DO IT")


class ConcreteThingTwo(AbstractThing):
    def do_something(self):
        print("concretethingtwo did something in a way concretethingtwo would do it")


class ThingType(Enum):
    ONE = ConcreteThingOne
    TWO = ConcreteThingTwo


def func_that_does_something_with_thing(thing_type: ThingType):
    thing: AbstractThing = thing_type.value()
    thing.do_something()

I found that it could be a kind of pattern but I am not really sure.
What I like about it:

The thing_type being an enum offers the user of this could or his IDE a suggestion on what value is possible (as opposed to when using a dict).
Mapping the enum names to the classes lets you skip a lot of "boilerplate code" that one would get when writing a factory (potentially big and ugly if else ladder).


You've already answered yourself in the title. A search with those keywords would yield good results explaining the pattern already.

This corresponds to a factory pattern, which is natuarally implemented in Python (and does not need the boilerplate as in C++). To be honest I would not explictily give it a name [*] as this is naturally supported by Python and actually quite idiomatic.
That said, it is actually much simpler in Python:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from enum import Enum


class AbstractThing(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        pass


class ConcreteThingOne(AbstractThing):
    def do_something(self):
        print("CONCRETETHINGONE DID SOMETHING IN A WAY CONCRETETHINGONE WOULD DO IT")


class ConcreteThingTwo(AbstractThing):
    def do_something(self):
        print("concretethingtwo did something in a way concretethingtwo would do it")


def func_that_does_something_with_thing(thing_class: Type[AbstractThing]):
    thing: AbstractThing = thing_class()  # default construct
    thing.do_something()

So no enum required, just use the class as a variable itself. Not using an enum has no immediate drawbacks. Surely one does not get the autocomplete in the IDE, but is that really worth it?
Also the original thing_type.value() line I find really hard to read. In fact thing_type.value is just a property, which returns a Python class (the enum value). Then you default construct an object from that by using the call operator. It looks as if .value() is a function call, but it isnt. I find this a bit non-idiomatic and would avoid it (and the enum-trick) altogether.
If one really wants all classes in a namespace and does not like the long names, I would put aliases of the classes in a separate (sub-)module, e.g. named 'factory' where for instance also 'func_that_does_something_with_thing' resides in. The use of an enum looks abusive to me
#factory.py
from ..base import AbstractThing
from ..impl1 import ConcreteThingOne as ONE
from ..impl2 import ConcreteThingTwo as TWO

def func_that_does_something_with_thing(thing_class: Type[AbstractThing]):
    thing: AbstractThing = thing_class()  # default construct
    thing.do_something()


and use factory.func_that_does_something_with_thing(factory.ONE)
[*] These patterns (or at least some of them) come from C++, where standard tasks are difficult to do correct. In Python this is different and had we Python before C++, many of these "Patterns"  would not even have a name.

This is the factory method or strategy pattern. These patterns have very good extensibility, like  adding new types is straightforward, just create a new class and update the enum. You can find out more about them here: https://realpython.com/factory-method-python/ and https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy/python/example

It is definitely not a factory method. We don't have a factory / creator class here to create a concrete class instance dynamically based on some runtime available information.

@PeterCsala Thank you for the clarification, Peter. While this isn’t a strict Factory Method pattern, it shares similarities due to its extensibility and ease of adding new types. By using an enum to map to classes, we achieve a similar outcome without the need for a formal creator class. For a purer factory implementation, introducing a dedicated creator class would align more closely with the classic definition.

It is a Strategy implementation.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern
There is a contract (AbstractThing) which defines the strategy, 2 implementations (ConcreteThingOne and ConcreteThingTwo) and the context (func_that_does_something_with_thing).
Wikipedia at the link above gives a lot of details, including diagrams that help understanding.
